# How to set a default search result in a search bar?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to a built a search bar using JavaScript and json. I need the search bar to show some default search results when any visitors visit the page. I set the value to search bar and tried but there is no  search result until the user remove a text inside the search field. How can i show a default or predefined search results whenever a person visit the page.

```js
const search = document.getElementById("search");
const matchList = document.getElementById("match-list");

const searchWorker = async (searchText) => {
  const res = await fetch("workers.json");
  const states = await res.json();
  let matches = states.filter((state) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`${searchText}`, "gi");
    return state.name.match(regex);
  });
  if (searchText.length === 0) {
    matches = [];
    matchList.innerHTML = "";
  }
  outputHtml(matches);
};

const outputHtml = (matches) => {
  if (matches.length > 0) {
    const html = matches
      .map(
        (match) => `<div class=" search-result">
            <a href="${match.portfolio}">
            ${match.name} - ${match.age}<br/>
            <small>Salery - ${match.salary}</small>
            </a></div>
            `
      )
      .join("");
    matchList.innerHTML = html;
  }
};
search.addEventListener("input", () => searchWorker(search.value));
```

```html
 <input id="search" type="search" value="sam" />
    <div id="match-list"></div>
      </div>
```

My json file:

```
[
{
    "name": "sam",
    "age": "26",
    "salary": "20000",
    "portfolio": "https://www.example.com/1"
},
{
    "name": "tony",
    "age": "30",
    "salary": "30000",
    "portfolio": "https://www.example.com/2"
},
{
    "name": "sam",
    "age": "24",
    "salary": "15000",
    "portfolio": "https://www.example.com/3"
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run the `searchWorker(search.value);` function in the top level code. Like this:

```js
search.addEventListener("input", () => searchWorker(search.value));
searchWorker(search.value);
```

This will show the results for the default value of the input.

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/OJmXrMM